# How to unit test code that makes HTTP requests with twisted.web.client.Agent?

Tags: twisted

I'm looking for hints or examples that illustrate how to unit test code that makes HTTP requests using twisted.web.client.Agent.

Is it possible to use the real Agent in tests and configure it to connect to a fake HTTP server using StringTransport (no real TCP connetion)?

Or is it better to mock out the Agent and inject a mock into classes that use the Agent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is certainly possible to use a real `Agent`.  You must construct the `Agent` instance with a reactor as first argument; as such, you can provide a *fake* reactor, such as [`MemoryReactor`](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/test/proto_helpers.py#L374).  Although that's a pretty handy way to get down in the guts of what `Agent` is doing, it's really mostly useful for testing `Agent` itself.  Injecting a fake `Agent` is many times an easier route, because its api is both shallow (almost everything passes through `Agent.request` and simple (it returns an `IResponse`)

Comment: See also https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/4024 and https://github.com/iffy/agentforhire

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to go the mock route. Are you aware of an existing IResponse implementation that could be used for tests? It seems fairly straightforward to roll my own, but maybe there is no such need?

Comment: You can use the same implementation returned by Agent, namely `twisted.web.client.Response`, it works fine even when not connected to a real transport.  Alternatively, a trivial implementation is also sufficient: `collections.NamedTuple("MyResponse", "version code phrase headers length deliverBody")`