# Using twisted in doctest

Tags: python, twisted, doctest

I'm having trouble using twisted together with `doctest`. I'm trying to [open a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33708936/408556) like so:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
from twisted.internet.fdesc import readFromFD, setNonBlocking
from twisted.internet.task import react


def asyncFunc(filename):
    """Description.

    Examples:
        >>> def run(reactor, filename):
        ...     d = asyncFunc(filename)
        ...     return d.addCallback(print)
        >>>
        >>> try:
        ...     react(run, ['hello.txt'])
        ... except SystemExit:
        ...     pass
        hello world
        <BLANKLINE>
    """
    with open(filename) as f:
        d = Deferred()
        fd = f.fileno()
        setNonBlocking(fd)
        readFromFD(fd, d.callback)
        return d
```

It works fine with just one test, but for more than one I get a `ReactorNotRestartable` error.

```
def anotherAsyncFunc(filename):
    """Description.

    Examples:
        >>> def run(reactor, filename):
        ...     d = anotherAsyncFunc(filename)
        ...     return d.addCallback(print)
        >>>
        >>> try:
        ...     react(run, ['hello.txt'])
        ... except SystemExit:
        ...     pass
        hello world
        <BLANKLINE>
    """
    with open(filename) as f:
        d = Deferred()
        fd = f.fileno()
        setNonBlocking(fd)
        readFromFD(fd, d.callback)
        return d
```

I then read about [`MemoryReactor`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18079638/408556) and tried this:

```
def anotherAsyncFunc(filename):
    """Description.

    Examples:
        >>> from twisted.test.proto_helpers import MemoryReactor
        >>> reactor = MemoryReactor()
        >>>
        >>> def run(reactor, filename):
        ...     d = anotherAsyncFunc(filename)
        ...     return d.addCallback(print)
        >>>
        >>> try:
        ...     react(run, ['hello.txt'], reactor)
        ... except SystemExit:
        ...     pass
        hello world
        <BLANKLINE>
    """
    with open(filename) as f:
        d = Deferred()
        fd = f.fileno()
        setNonBlocking(fd)
        readFromFD(fd, d.callback)
        return d
```

But that gives me an `'MemoryReactor' object has no attribute 'addSystemEventTrigger'` `AttributeError`. Any idea on the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly identified that `MemoryReactor` does not provide the interface `IReactorCore`.  The proper thing to do would be to contribute an implementation of `IReactorCore` to `MemoryReactor` so that the second example would work as desired.  Please open a ticket and do that :).

Comment: Thanks for the help @glyph. I'm new to the whole interface concept so could you please point me to an existing ticket or example I could follow as a guide?

Comment: I can't think of a specific ticket, but it's not complicated; [`IReactorCore`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.4.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorCore.html) has a bunch of methods and attributes, just add those attributes to `MemoryReactor` (and then add `IReactorCore` to its `@implements` line).  Interfaces are just a documented description of what features a particular object has to have.

Comment: gotcha.... do they actually need to do anything or can I just use `pass` for all of them?

Comment: Well, [patch submitted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/8113) and the tests pass so I guess all is ok :).

Comment: Thanks very much for your contribution, we'll discuss further on the ticket!